# Creating build file while debugging remote java application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I'm trying to debug a remote java application in eclipse which runs on tomcat and receives data from frontend.

While debugging it gets me from frontend to the breakpoint in eclipse, but in variables window I can't see the newest changes I have made. It is a cloned repository, so every time it takes me to the original code whatever I've added there. I've tried  exporting a jar-file, but it didn't help. There's also nothing in logs. I'm inexperienced so I cannot think another solution out. Hope, someone has an idea

edited

I guess the problem is with the build.xml file. Every time I make changes to the code, I need to export a jar-file into WEB-INF/lib/ directory and restart tomcat and the debugging session. Eclipse should do it self, and there is also an ant-utils directory, where I guess, it should write this file, so I still cannot figure it out, why it doesn't

Comment: please take a look at this site this completely guided how to do this:
https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-remote-debug-with-eclipse/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. i have my project running and debugging runs on port 8000 without any error. the thing is, it doesn't see the changes i've made

Comment: so in order to see changes you've made, you should restart your application. please try it and you'll see changes.

Comment: surely i've done it already. i thought, there should be something i've omitted to correctly configure the projects. but anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hotswap makes use of updating class files, so you have to upload them to the server somehow. That's not automatic. During development, you might want to use the classes folder instead of a jar and rig a way for it to sync when the local classpath output folder contents change.